# Is this the correct way to write asynchronous code in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to get my hands dirty with some node.js code. I understand the theory of events and callbacks and asynchronous techniques, but this does not mean it is easy to really produce code in "the right manner".

The following is my (reallife) example of a middleware. A simple HTTP server listens for requests and on `/get`, it queries our backend and presents the data from there to the client.

```
var http = require('http')
var https = require('https')
var url = require('url')

var backendOptions = {
    port: 1414,
    hostname: 'data.backend.com',
    path: '/bulk',
    auth: 'user:$ecret'
}

var backendGet = function(callback) {
    https.get(backendOptions, function(res) {
        var content = ''
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            content += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', function() {
            callback(content)
        })
    })
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    switch(url.parse(req.url).pathname) {
        case '/get':
            backendGet(function(content) {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
                res.write(content)
                res.end()
            })
            break
        default:
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
            res.write('<p>It works!</p>')
            res.end()
    }
}).listen(8080, 'localhost')
```

This code works - **but is this how I write code in node.js?** The client should be served when the data from backend is available, so I'm calling `backendGet()` with a function as callback to operate on the `res` object as soon as there is no more backend data to be read.

General comments and critique are welcome, too!

Alex

Comment: You can drop `var server = ` if you have no intention of using that reference any further, since you are already chaining the `listen`. You should always use the `(err, [args,] callback)` pattern for async calls. The code is ok for a small home/learning project :)

Comment: This might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty solid. I would make a couple tweaks, the biggest being, it is conventional for callbacks to have function signature `function callback(err, result1, result2..)`. And you call `callback(null, content)` if it worked, and `callback('Problem')` or `callback(new Error('Problem'))` if it didn't.

I added error handling using the above convention. AFAIK lack of trailing semicolons doesn't break anything, but I added them out of force of habit. I moved the anonymous function that handles requests into its own function to make it clearer. And finally I reindented to 2 spaces because it makes callback hell much more manageable.

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var url = require('url');

var backendOptions = {
  port: 1414,
  hostname: 'data.backend.com',
  path: '/bulk',
  auth: 'user:$ecret'
};

var backendGet = function(callback) {
  https.get(backendOptions, function(res) {
    var content = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      content += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      callback(null, content);
    });
    res.on('error', function(err) {  
      // i didn't look up this syntax but I think this is how errors are signified
      console.log('Request error: '+err);
      callback('Request error');
    });
  });
};

function handler(req, res){
  switch(url.parse(req.url).pathname) {
    case '/get':
      backendGet(function(err, content) {
        if(err){
          res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          res.write('Request error');
          return res.end();
        };
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write(content);
        res.end();
      })
      break;
    default:
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write('<p>It works!</p>');
      res.end();
  }
};

var server = http.createServer(handler).listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

Comment: +1 Using this pattern will also allow you to use libraries such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) easily when you start getting into callback hell.